# swift, back endless: Publish options

Tags: ios, swift, messenger, backendless

I'm doing mini messenger. I have list of friends. And I want to when somebody send me some message, that person who send me message, go at the top of list of friends. How to do this? Below I'll show you me method which called when I send message.

```
func publishMessageAsync(message: String) {
    let history = MessageHistory()
    print("message is: \(message)")
    history.message = message//text sms
    history.user1 = Backendless.sharedInstance().userService.currentUser
    history.user2 = self.friend.user2!
    self.messageHistories.append(history)
    self.chatTableView.reloadData()
```

MessageHistory is my class, which store history of messages))

```
    Backendless.sharedInstance().messaging.publish(history.user2!.objectId, message: message,
        response:{ ( messageStatus : MessageStatus!) -> () in
            print("MessageStatus = \(messageStatus.status) ['\(messageStatus.messageId)']")

            self.messageTextField.text = ""
            self.messageTextField.resignFirstResponder()

            // call function for saving
            self.saveMessageHistory(message)
        },
            error: { ( fault : Fault!) -> () in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: so you have a list of people and you know which messages you have received from them and when they arrived ?

Comment: I just send message from user1(current user) to the user2.objectId

Comment: you need to explain what data you have if you're going to solve this